# A rectangle in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

How can I draw or put a Rectangle in Xamarin.Android(in Visual Studio) by designer(Main.axml) or from code or Strings.xml file ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to approach this.

1. Use a `Drawable` xml file where you define a rectangle.
2. Use a 9-patch image representing a rectangle.
3. Use an image showing a rectangle.
4. Create a custom `View` where you override the `OnDraw` method and draw the rectangle there.

For **1.** you can do something like:

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

    <size android:height="20dp" />
</shape>
```

and then use it for the background in a `View` when you define it in an layout file.

For the last approach you can do something like:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.OS;

namespace AndroidApplication2
{
    [Activity(Label = "AndroidApplication2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            var rectView = new RectangleView(this);
            SetContentView(rectView);
        }
    }

    public class RectangleView : View
    {
        public RectangleView(Context context) 
            : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            var paint = new Paint {Color = Color.Blue, StrokeWidth = 3};
            canvas.DrawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark this as an answer if it helped you